# AngularJS Factory using Visual Studio Snippet

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, angularjs-factory, visual-studio-2015

I Have this AngularJS factory that's is working fine, However when i try to accommodate it in auto generated visual studio snippet for AngularJS factory, It does not happen and i can not get the syntax right.This is my factory

```
angular.module('payrollApp').factory('countries', function ($http) {
   return {
       getCountries: function (callback) {              
            $http.get('countries.json').success(callback);              
       }
   }});
```

But how should i change it so i can use Visual Studio auto generated code. This is the auto generated snippet:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('factory', factory);

factory.$inject = ['$http'];

function factory($http) {
    var service = {
        getData: getData
    };

    return service;

    function getData() { }
}})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('payrollApp')
        .factory('countries', factory);
    factory.$inject = ['$http'];
    function factory($http) {
        var service = {
            getCountries: getCountries
        };
        return service;
        function getCountries(callback) {
      $http.get('countries.json').success(callback);          
     }
    }})();
```